# How to do phone authentication in flutter using http post request?

Tags: http, flutter, verification, one-time-password

I am trying but in response did not get entered number. I have one post api which give me an OTP which bring me in next screen for registration.

```
//In below code i get response.

createPost(String url, {Map body}) async {
                            return http
                                .post(url, body: body)
                                .then((http.Response response) {
                              print("Response" + response.body);//response get from api

                              return Post.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
                            });
                          }
    //I am taking number as a string
                          Post newPost = new Post(
                              usernumber: _numbercontroller.text,
                              contrycode: code.toString()
                          );//contrycode taken ans var datatype
                          Post p = await createPost(url, body: newPost.toMap());

                          print("Number --> " + newPost.usernumber);//here did not get mobile number
                        },
```

When I entered mobile number I get otp number from API for registration.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the API. If entered phone number is not getting means your response is getting something different. Kindly elaborate the response from API.